# c : How to initialize mulitdimensional arrays from other arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization

got some problem with my C Code:

**Input: int array[16]**

**(whished)Output: array2[4][4] so the first 4 elements in array2[0][1]-array2[0][3]**

I got something like this now, but I didn't figured out why it is not working; 
I know that array[1] = *(array + 1);

Would be great if sb could help me out.

```
int write_from_state(int *state[][4])
{
    encryption[0] =  state[0][0];
    encryption[1] =  state[1][0];
    encryption[2] =  state[2][0];
    encryption[3] =  state[3][0];
    encryption[4] =  state[0][1];
    encryption[5] =  state[1][1];
    encryption[6] =  state[2][1];
    encryption[7] =  state[3][1];
    encryption[8] =  state[0][2];
    encryption[9] =  state[1][2];
    encryption[10] = state[2][2];
    encryption[11] = state[3][2];
    encryption[12] = state[0][3];
    encryption[13] = state[1][3];
    encryption[14] = state[2][3];
    encryption[15] = state[3][3];

    return encryption;
}
```

**Error I get**

*warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     state[0][0] = msg[0] ;*

Comment: Are you sure of the line `int *state[][4]` ? There is 2 errors in this single line. Also, you should definitely use loops or `memcpy` to copy your arrays.

Comment: The declaration `int *state[][4]` say that `state` is an array of arrays of four pointers to `int`. I think you meant only `int state[][4]`. Also you return `int` not `int *`.

Comment: And you should probably be using loops instead.

Comment: By the way, the warning message doesn't match the code you show. When asking questions please make sure that the [mcve] replicates the problem you ask about. And that the error message you show is a copy-paste (in full and complete) from the code you show.

Comment: Note that in C, "initialize" means something more specific than "assign a value for the first time".  It's more like "specify the value that an object has when it comes into existence", and that's not what your code is doing.

Comment: "Guess the type of my variables by reading my mind" questions are starting to become _very_ tiresome. When posting a question about type conflicts, it might be wise to include the types involved as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int *write_from_state(int *dest, int *src, size_t rowLength, size_t nRows)
{
    int *tmp = dest;
    while(nRows--)
    {
        memcpy(tmp, src, sizeof(*src) * rowLength);
        tmp += rowLength;
        src += rowLength;
    }
    return dest;
}
```

or just

`memcpy(dest, src, nRows * rowLength * sizoef(*src));`

or even

`int *dest = (void)src;`

and then `dest[x]`;